# How do I get a reference to a Geopoint field in a FireStore document?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints

I'm still new in programming, but I have a background in Java, I'm making a small android project to mimic Uber, I'm following tutorials mostly and trying to figure things out, now I'm stuck with a Geopoint field in a document that I can't reach, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.[This is the database I'm working on, I'm trying to reach the field with the line underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2P3n.jpg)

Comment: Please post what have you done so far and explain how you get driver id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("driversAvailable").document("6p......ZK5")
    .get().addOnSuccess{ snapshot -> 
               val l = snapshot.get("l")
           }
```

This is just a sample how to get `Geo Point` which is l in this case. But its not good approach to hard code the `ID` of driver.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, I'm trying to implement this code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rglV.png) using Firestore but I'm struggling.